# Where condition based on parameter value

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have the following procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE LoadSoldItens  
        @DateStart DATETIME,  
        @DateEnd DATETIME,
        @SectionId INT = NULL
AS                  
BEGIN                  
    SELECT SectionId, Name INTO #Sections  
        FROM LoadSections(@SectionId)    

    SELECT S.Id AS SoldId,   
           S.Quantity AS SoldQuantity,   
      FROM SoldItens S WITH(NOLOCK)  
        LEFT JOIN #Sections SC ON S.SectionId = SC.SectionId
     WHERE (ISNULL(S.SoldDate, @DateStart) BETWEEN @DateStart AND @DateEnd)  
     -- AND --Here i'm stuck ....
END
```

The parameter @SectionId is optional and if the user sends NULL or -10 for @SectionId parameter, then i need to retrieve all data that have S.SectionId null value or any value.

If the user sends @SectionId > 0, then i need retrieve the data that have S.Section = @SectionId.

My last try was:

```
AND (ISNULL(@SectionId, S.SectionId) IS NULL 
            OR ISNULL(@SectionId, S.SectionId) IS NOT NULL)
-- How to check @SectionId = -10 or @SectionId > 0
```

Anyone could give me a hand, please?

Thank in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just like this... compare to section id if not null or to itself if null.

```
AND ISNULL(@SectionId, S.SectionId) = S.SectionID
```

to check for -10 do this:

```
WHERE (...
   AND ISNULL(@SectionId, S.SectionId) = S.SectionID)
   OR @SectionID = -10
```

---

Please run the following full query, it will work:

```
SELECT S.Id AS SoldId,   
       S.Quantity AS SoldQuantity,   
FROM SoldItens S WITH(NOLOCK)  
LEFT JOIN #Sections SC ON SC.SectionId = SC.SectionId
WHERE ISNULL(S.SoldDate, @DateStart) BETWEEN @DateStart AND @DateEnd  
  AND (
     ISNULL(@SectionId, S.SectionId) = S.SectionID)
     OR @SectionID = -10 
  )
```

Comment: If i do it, i'll only return rows that S.SectionId is not null and if @SectionId is null, i need to retrieve rows with any values in S.SectionId ( including null values )

Comment: @placplacboom - that is what it does, if @ SectionId is null it matches everything.

Comment: And -10 comes from "exec LoadSoldItens '01/01/2013', '12/31/2014', -10'

Comment: @placplacboom - I wrote the full query for you there.  It will solve the problem.

Comment: I was trying to compare using "=" NULL values on column. This is why wasn't working. :)

Answer (score 0):

Although you can do this, you probably shouldn't. The optimizer would need to review your bind variables before it would be able to formulate the correct execution plan.

A better way to handle this would be to just do the logic in TSQL which would give the optimizer a clear understanding of the desired result set. Also consider rewriting

(ISNULL(S.SoldDate, @DateStart) BETWEEN @DateStart AND @DateEnd)

to be (S.SoldDate BETWEEN @DateStart AND @DateEnd or S.SoldDate is Null)

```
CREATE PROCEDURE LoadSoldItens  
        @DateStart DATETIME,  
        @DateEnd DATETIME,
        @SectionId INT = NULL
AS                  
BEGIN                  
    SELECT SectionId, Name INTO #Sections  
        FROM LoadSections(@SectionId)   

    if  @SectionId is null or @SectionId = -10
    begin
        SELECT S.Id AS SoldId,   
               S.Quantity AS SoldQuantity,   
          FROM SoldItens S WITH(NOLOCK)  
            LEFT JOIN #Sections SC ON SC.SectionId = SC.SectionId
         WHERE (S.SoldDate BETWEEN @DateStart AND @DateEnd  or S.SoldDate is NULL)
    end
    else
    begin

        SELECT S.Id AS SoldId,   
               S.Quantity AS SoldQuantity,   
          FROM SoldItens S WITH(NOLOCK)  
            LEFT JOIN #Sections SC ON SC.SectionId = SC.SectionId
         WHERE (S.SoldDate BETWEEN @DateStart AND @DateEnd  or S.SoldDate is NULL)
         and s.SectionID = @SectionId
    end
END
```

Comment: Can't i do it using more conditions on where clause?

Comment: Yes, Hogan's answer shows you how to add it to the where clause.